# JS Алгоритм добавления цифр в массив

Tags: javascript, html, алгоритм

Я хочу реализовать такое:
Я добавляю задачу(элемент с классом `.task`и атрибутом `data-id`) через input, а потом информация сохраняется в `localStorage`
Я код написал таким образом, что атрибуту `data-id` задаётся просто кол-во элементов с классом `.task`
Я хочу сделать так: например, на сайте есть элементы с атрибутами 1,2,3,4,5. Я удалил элементы 2,3. На сайте остались элементы: 1,4,5. При добавлении нового элемента атрибут надо сравнить с тем, что есть на сайте и от самого минимального добавить. В данном случае мой алгорит должен пойти таким образом: 1 есть, такой атрибут не добавлять, 2 нету, значит можно создать элемент с таким атрибутом. Если добавить ещё элемент, то у него будет `data-id` 3, а потом уже создастся 6, так как 4 и 5 уже есть.
Собственно я не могу понять как такой алгоритм мне написать, подскажите пожалуйста.
Я над этим парюсь, чтобы добавлять элементы в localStorage по ключам, которые будут равны `data-id`, возможно есть какое-то решение получше, чем выставление элементам id

Вот код, который добавляет в глобальный массив `arr` элементы, но я не понимаю как правильно задать условия, чтобы в массив добавлялись `data-id` только **один** раз, которые неравны друг другу. Мне массив нужен для того, чтобы сравнить его элементы по значениям и добавить тот `data-id`, которого нету

```
for (let i = 0; i < task.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < task.length; j++) {
            if (task[i].getAttribute('data-id') == 
            task[j].getAttribute('data-id')) {
                arr.push(task[i].getAttribute('data-id'));
            }
        }
    }
block.setAttribute('data-id', task.length);
```

```js
let task, tasks, task__close;
let add__button = document.querySelector('.add__button');
let add__input = document.querySelector('.add__input');
let arr = [];

function addElem() {
 if (add__input.value === '') {
  return false;
 }
 let block = document.createElement('div');
 let taskId;
 tasks = document.querySelector('.tasks');
 task = document.querySelectorAll('.task');
 block.className = 'task';
 for (let i = 0; i < task.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < task.length; j++) {
   if (task[i].getAttribute('data-id') == 
   task[j].getAttribute('data-id')) {
    arr.push(task[i].getAttribute('data-id'));
   }
  }
 }
 block.setAttribute('data-id', task.length);
 block.innerHTML = '<div class="task__close"></div>';
 block.innerHTML += add__input.value;
 tasks.prepend(block);
 task__close = document.querySelector('.task__close');
 add__input.value = '';
 startClose();
} // function addElem()

function startClose() {
 task__close = document.querySelectorAll('.task__close');
 for (let i = 0; i < task__close.length; i++) {
  task__close[i].addEventListener('click', (event) => {
   event.path[1].remove();
  });
 }
} // function startClose()

add__button.addEventListener('click', () => {
 addElem();
});

add__input.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
 if (event.code == 'Enter' || event.keyCode == '13' || event.key == 'Enter') {
  addElem();
 }
});

startClose();
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700&display=swap');

*, *:before, *:after {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

html{
 scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 color: black;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, ul {
 margin: 0;
}

ul {
 list-style: none;
}

img {
 display: block;
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}

.container {
 max-width: 1100px;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.container.fluid {
 max-width: 100%; 
}

.spheres {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
}

.sphere {
 border-right: 1px solid black;
 flex-grow: 1;
 padding: 15px 0;
}

.sphere:first-child {
 border-left: 1px solid black;
}

.sphere  .svg__icon {
 max-width: 70px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.sphere  .svg__icon img {
 width: 100%;
}

.sphere__title {
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 10px;
 font-size: 20px;
}

.add {
 background-color: #46a049;
 padding: 25px 0;
}

.add__title {
 font-size: 22px;
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
}

.add__input-wrapper {
 position: relative;
 max-width: 500px;
 margin: 10px auto 0;
 padding: 0 15px;
}

.add__input {
 outline: 0;
 font-family: inherit;
 font-size: inherit;
 border: 1px solid white;
 display: block;
 border-radius: 5px;
 padding: 7px 55px 7px 20px;
 width: 100%;
}

.add__button {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 right:15px;
 transform: translate(0, -50%);
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
}

.add__button:before {
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 content: '';
 top: 50%;
 transform: translate(-40%, -50%) rotate(90deg);
 width: 2px;
 background-color: #91a8c4;
 height: 20px;
 right: 40%;
}

.add__button:after {
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 content: '';
 top: 50%;
 transform: translate(-40%, -50%);
 width: 2px;
 background-color: #91a8c4;
 height: 20px;
 right: 40%;
}

.add__button:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
}

.add__button:hover:before {
 background-color: #3675bc;
}

.add__button:hover:after {
 background-color: #3675bc;
}

.tasks {
 margin-top: 20px;
 padding: 0 20px;
}

.task {
 position: relative;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #f0f0f0;
 padding: 10px 0;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
}

.task__close {
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 border: 1px solid gray;
 border-radius: 50%;
 margin-right: 15.5px;
 position: relative;
}

.task__close:before {
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 content: '';
 right: 6px;
 top: 3px;
 transform: rotate(45deg);
 width: 5px;
 height: 10px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(128,128,128,0.8);
 border-right: 1px solid rgba(128,128,128,0.8);
 opacity: 0;
 transition: .2s linear opacity;
}

.task__close:hover {
 background-color: rgba(128,128,128,0.2);
 cursor: pointer;
}

.task__close:hover:before {
 opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

 <section class="section">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="spheres">
    <div class="sphere health">
     <div class="svg__icon">
      <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/148/148838.svg" alt="">
     </div>
     <div class="sphere__title">
      Здоровье
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sphere intelligence">
     <div class="svg__icon">
      <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1491/1491214.svg" alt="">
     </div>
     <div class="sphere__title">
      Развитие
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sphere sociality">
     <div class="svg__icon">
      <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1078/1078011.svg" alt="">
     </div>
     <div class="sphere__title">
      Отношения
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>  <!-- .spheres -->
  </div> <!-- .container -->

  <div class="container fluid">
   <div class="add">
    <div class="add__title">
     Добавить задачу
    </div>
    <div class="add__input-wrapper">
     <input type="text" placeholder="Бег 1 км" class="add__input">
     <div class="add__button"></div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div> <!-- .container.fluid -->

  <div class="container">
   <div class="tasks">
    <div class="task" data-id="0">
     <div class="task__close"></div>
     Моя первая задача
    </div>
   </div>
  </div> <!-- .container -->
 
 </section>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var arr = [2,5,6];

function addNext(arr) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] != i) {
      arr.splice(i, 0, i);
      return arr;
    }
  }
  arr.push(arr.length);
  return arr;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
console.log(JSON.stringify(addNext(arr)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(addNext(arr)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(addNext(arr)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(addNext(arr)));
```

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, не пойму, почему если задать `arr = [0]` и вызвать `addNext(arr)`, то я получаю массив [1, 0]

Comment: @МихаилКамахин Потому что мне показалось, что это массив с натуральными числами. Если нужно, чтобы начиналось с нуля, уберите `+ 1` из всех `i + 1`.